# How to export specific version of project on lwc playground

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-playground

I am trying to export all my projects from the live playground to take backup. I am following [this doc](https://github.com/forcedotcom/lwc-playground-export#usage) and I have installed the **Playground Export CLI Plugin** using the below command.

```
$ sfdx plugins:install playground-export
```

I was able to download the project with the below command.

```
$ sfdx playground:export -i <ID> --name myproj
```

I have several versions of the projects, like below.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/HGeWXkX-7/1/edit
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/HGeWXkX-7/2/edit
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/HGeWXkX-7/3/edit

Where `HGeWXkX-7` is the id of the project and versions are 1, 2, 3.

But the command downloads the only most recent version of the project, which is 3. Is there any way to download the specific version? or all versions? I could not find anything in the doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way. Appending `/<version-number>` to the `<ID>` downloads that specific version.

```
$ sfdx playground:export -i <ID>/<version#> --name myproj
```

I was able to download version 1 using the below command.

```
$ sfdx playground:export -i HGeWXkX-7/1 --name myproj
```

Version 2 using the below command.

```
$ sfdx playground:export -i HGeWXkX-7/2 --name myproj
```